# Grub Boot-Loader Not Getting Repaired

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

I am getting no screen for selection of which OS to boot. I installed windows 8 over Ubuntu 13.10.

In Boot-Repair i selected Recommended repair but later the repair failed and it gave me this URL directing to the problem: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7244788/.

Can anyone study my problem at above URL and help me out?

Thank you!

---

The computer directly boots to Windows 8

Comment: Did you able to boot any one of the OS's?

Comment: The computer directly boots to Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your GRUB paste, you installed GRUB on `/dev/sdb1` which seems to be a removable drive. GRUB further detects that `/dev/sda3` which is your hard disk has some metadata in windows cache which happens when windows is in hibernate/sleep. So, In order to be able to see the boot selection screen, shutdown the computer from windows and then manually start it.

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you for your reply. Though the second time it directly booted to Ubuntu. After shutting down Ubuntu, the next time I tried it worked!